# why this javascript cannot function that we purpose in popup form

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

```
    </br>
```

s_foot">
    *

use ajax.jquery as control event. like $("#save").click(function(){.....});

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var wp;
var posisi;
var pid;
var pname;
var pdate;
```

on this script i try to get value by element id and use POST as methode. here aksi.php code

```
    <?php
    //conect to database
    //get the value

 ($_POST['pname']);
        $ProductionDate = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pdate']);
        $save = mssql_query("Insert tblTrnProduct value('$ProductID', '$ProductName', '$WH', '$Posisi', '$ProductionDate')
        WHERE Posisi='$Posisi'");
        if($save){
        echo "sukses";
        }else{
        echo "error";
        }
        }
?>
```

on aksi.php no value were record. c'z when i use `<?php print_r($_POST) ?>` has a emty result. and of course when i run this in browser alwas say "ERROR..penyimpanan data GAGAL"
.what the problem? please advice...with code sample will more appreciate..

Comment: Have you used any developer consoles such as firebug for firefox? if so.. What are your errors, furthermore. Do your own research into your bugs prior to posting here, we are not here to cipher through lines and lines of code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Rz2PZ/3/

Comment: yes it's working after i restart my computer, i didn't change my code...waste my time 2 hour to find this problem. and make me ashame ask silly question...anyway tq so much for the answer....:)

Answer (score 1):

You failed to include jQuery in your jsFiddle. The `$ is undefined` error in your browser's console should have alerted you to this.

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle does work, you simply forgot to include `jQuery`. Have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/Rz2PZ/2/ . However,  I expect that you probably included `jQuery` in your real project, so could it be that the `exit` function doesnt exist in your code?

Answer (score 1):

jsfiddle.net/

if you use jquery code , need load jquery (Frameworks & Extensions select box)